# Show/hide Edittext inside listview becomes invisible when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, popup, android-edittext

I have a custom Listview whose adapter extends BaseAdapter class. Inside every row in listview there is an invisible EditText. it get visible to only particular row which has been click and on rest of the row it remains invisible.Problem comes when I touch edittext to get keyboard, as soon as keyboard appears, listview gets recycle and edittext again become invisible.
I am looking for a solution in which either keyboard comes with focus on edittext as soon as that row is selected or edittext does not disapear when keyboard is poped-up.Following is the adapter I am using:

this is my adapter xml file
saved_option_adapter_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/lineItem"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textLine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittext_qty"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:hint="cvv"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my getView Method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
             { 
             final ViewHolder holder;
                 if (convertView == null) 
                     {
                         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_options_adapter_content, null);
                         holder = new ViewHolder();
                         holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLine);
                         holder.Edittext = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_qty);

                        editTextList.add(holder.Edittext);                  
                         convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                         {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(final View v) 
                                     { 
selected_Txt="";
                                     if(view==null || view!=v){
                                     v.post(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                view=v;
                                                  ViewHolder holder = ((ViewHolder)v.getTag()); 
                                                 holder.Edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                  holder.Edittext.requestFocus();
                                                 holder.Edittext.setCursorVisible(true);
                                                holder.Edittext.setFocusable(true); 
                                               if(selectedHolder != null ){
                                                selectedHolder.Edittext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                }
                                                selectedHolder = holder; 
                                            }
                                        }); 
                                     }
                                     }
                         });

                         convertView.setTag(holder);
                     } 
                 else 
                     {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    ((ViewHolder)convertView.getTag()).Edittext.setTag(title.get(position));
                     }

                  convertView.setTag(holder);
                 return convertView;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see listview in your code. Maybe ArrayAdapter can help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: payOptionList = (ListView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.list);
  payOptionList.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: I am not having problem in creating the ListView 
problem occurs with ListView recycle when keyboard pops up